# VPS server RAM question for JAVA

Tags: java, hosting, vps, ram

I am new to VPS hosting so my question could be a little stupid, but...

For example, some hosting company offers vps plan with 256mb ram. Can I configure JAVA to use all those 256mbs? Or some memory will be used to by linux?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign the entire 256 mb to the JVM, the OS will still use a significant portion for its own use.

Comment: Is it possible to find out how many resources will OS use in vps?

Comment: Sure, login to the machine and execute the command: `top` 
Then look at the line that starts with Mem:
This will give you a good idea of the memory usage on the machine.

Comment: @Ovid @user and make sure to note that cached memory can for most purposes be considered free memory

Answer (score 1):

Definitely some memory will be used the OS and any other software you may run.

You can control how much memory Java uses by specifying the following VM parameters:

`-Xms=64m` for initial heap size
`-Xmx=256m` for maximum heap size

Answer (score 0):

First get Total memory being used by other processes on peak load [without this java process].

> This may help you get started http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-memory-usage/

keep some extra *buffer* , think how much your program/server would require and based on that then decide on howmuch memory you need to dedicate to java.

I suggest refer to JVM tuning articles that relate to target JVM and OS before finalizing stats